# Laravel + Vue Js : How can i hide a bootstraps 4 modal on getting response from Axios request

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, vue.js

I am using Laravel 5 with VueJs. I have a simple bootstrap4 modal having 3 input fields. On click submit data is sent to the database using AXIOS post request.

Now I want when I get a response (success) that bootstrap modal should hide. How can I achieve this?

code :

```
<script>
    export default{
      data(){
        return{
          list:{
          name:'',
          email:'',
          phone:''
        }
      }

      },
      methods:{
        save(){
          axios.post('/phonebook',this.$data.list).then((response)=>console.log(response))
  .catch((error)=>console.log(error))
        }

      }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Use Bootstrap modal inbuilt Method `$('#myModal').modal('hide')`. Read more [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
methods: {
  // ...
  if(response.status===200) this.closeModal();
  // ...
  closeModal() {
    $('#modal').modal('hide');
  }
}
```